# Multiple foreign key

Tags: sql, database, modeling, database-performance

I have this following scenario in a application .

An entity called Structure ,another called Customer and another called Organization . All of this entities have optional 0->N Telephones , so , i have created 4 tables

```
Structure 
ID_STRUCTURE (PK)
NAME VARCHAR

Customer
ID_CUSTOMER (PK)
RGI VARCHAR

Organization
ID_ORGANIZATION (PK)
ALIAS VARCHAR

Telephone
ID_TELEPHONE
NUMBER
ID_STRUCTURE (FK)
ID_CUSTOMER (FK)
ID_ORGANIZATION (FK)
```

One of three foreigns key always have a value and another two always is filled with null .

Registers example :

```
ID_TELEPHONE NUMBER ID_STRUCTURE ID_COSTUMER ID_ORGANIZATION
      1       1234        1         null         null
      2       4322        null       1           null 
      3       4333        null      null         2
      4       4233        null      null         2
```

My DBA says that it's a wrong approach (and it's not normalized) and sugest N:N tables to avoid this nullables fk . But the business rules don't allow N:N suggestion . But this discussion it's about normalization .

I'm wrong and this approach is not normalized ? Or it's correct and has no conceitual problems ?

Comment: What happens when you have 2 customers that use the same phone?

Comment: number is unique and don't repeat across the table .

Answer (score 2):

It's not normalized because the values of ID_STRUCTURE ID_COSTUMER ID_ORGANIZATION are depend on each other's value. You must ensure that only one of the 3 properties is not null. And it waste space to store null values.

You can try this approach

```
TelephoneOwner
ID_Owner (PK)

Telephone
ID_TELEPHONE
NUMBER
ID_Owner (FK)

Structure 
ID_STRUCTURE (PK)
ID_Owner (FK)

Customer
ID_CUSTOMER (PK)
ID_Owner (FK)

Organization
ID_ORGANIZATION (PK)
ID_Owner (FK)
```

Add a new talbe TelephoneOwner. All the entities Structure, Customer and Organization are owners, so add ID_Owner field for them. Each telephone can be owned by one owner, so add an ID_Owner field too.

When you add a new entity such as Structure, add a new TelephoneOwner and a new Structure. When a entity get a phone, set the phone's ID_Owner to the entity's ID_Owner.

If there's no other specific information about the ownership, such as the expire date, to put in the TelephoneOwner table, you can ignore the TelephoneOwner table, and replace entities' ID_Owner field with ID_TELEPHONE.

```
Telephone
ID_TELEPHONE
NUMBER

Structure 
ID_STRUCTURE (PK)
ID_TELEPHONE (FK)

Customer
ID_CUSTOMER (PK)
ID_TELEPHONE (FK)

Organization
ID_ORGANIZATION (PK)
ID_TELEPHONE (FK)
```

Comment: The first solution is fine but a question . Always i will have a table with one column just for workaround those foreign key null values ? Seems sound to strange for me . The second example fails because force model do be 1:1 and the relation is  0:N optional no ?

Comment: If you have other information of the ownership, such as when the ownership began, and when the ownership will end, the TelephoneOwner table will not have only one column. Otherwise, the second model solves the one column problem. Does it fail because your DBMS doesn't allow it or your DBA says it's wrong? Isn't the two model identical when TelephoneOwner table is merged into Telephone table?

Comment: Seconds fails because force model be 1:1 when Structure can have 0 or many telephones. Customer can have 0 or many telephones. Organization can have 0 or many telephones. Structures can not repeat yourself like other entities Customer and Organization . Understand now ? I edit my question with more columns